# How to group digits in minibuffer when sending input to calc?

Tags: calc

Is it possible to send something like `200*100,000` as an input to calc?

[Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html) says `Long numbers can be hard to read if they have too many digits. Press d g (calc-group-digits) to enable Grouping mode, in which digits are displayed in clumps of 3 or 4 (depending on the current radix) separated by commas.`

When using `(calc-group-digits)` the digits are grouped in clumps of 3, for example the value of `200*100000` is shown as `20,000,000`. 
It would be great if it would be possible to also give the input in clumps of 3 separated by comma in the minibuffer. I tried `200*100,000` but it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure if what you want is doable with the current code, but `200*100*1000` is only one character longer than what you want.

Comment: @npostavs Yes that number was easy, but for a number like `123438478` is mot easy.

Comment: @npostavs for 200*100*1000 you need to switch to the algebraic mode, that means even more typing...

Comment: If `,` isn't used by `calc` at all, it would be possible to advise the function which reads input to strip out commas before it gets the string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the scientific notation `200e5` to input large numbers in `calc` (or even more clearly the engineering notation `20e6` for your case).